# Oracle database service could not be connected on ubuntu , ORA-27101: shared memory realm does not exist

Tags: oracle

I got a linux server with ubuntu 16.04 and successfully installed oracle 11gR2 on it. After system boot , I could use the following code startup oracle and do a simple query:

```
db@dbpc:~$ sudo lsnrctl start
db@dbpc:~$ sqlplus /nolog
SQL> conn / as sysdba
SQL> startup

SQL> select * from scott.dept;

    DEPTNO DNAME      LOC
---------- -------------- -------------
    10 ACCOUNTING     NEW YORK
    20 RESEARCH   DALLAS
    30 SALES      CHICAGO
    40 OPERATIONS     BOSTON
```

However I could not login via IP , for example if I use the following command:(after start the hole services)

```
db@dbpc:~$ sqlplus scott/123456@192.168.1.100:1521/orcl
```

It will shows:

```
SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.4.0 Production on Thu Dec 31 12:58:42 2020

Copyright (c) 1982, 2013, Oracle. All rights reserved.

ERROR:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
ORA-27101: shared memory realm does not exist
Linux-x86_64 Error: 2: No such file or directory
Process ID: 0
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0
```

Here's my setting files:

```
db@dbpc:/home/rogear/tools/oracle11g/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/network/admin$ cat listener.ora 
# listener.ora Network Configuration File: /home/rogear/tools/oracle11g/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/network/admin/listener.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.1.100)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )
ADR_BASE_LISTENER = /home/rogear/tools/oracle11g



db@dbpc:/home/rogear/tools/oracle11g/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/network/admin$ cat tnsnames.ora 
# tnsnames.ora Network Configuration File: /home/rogear/tools/oracle11g/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/network/admin/tnsnames.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

ORCL =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.1.100)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = orcl)
    )
  )
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Use the local connection and query `select name from v$active_services`. What service names appear?

Answer (score 2):

The first thing that is wrong is that Oracle is not certified nor was ever designed for Ubuntu.  Ubuntu is from an entirely different branch of the linux family.  Getting oracle to work at all on it is a hack, and beyond that, nothing is guaranteed.

Also note that your connection string (sqlplus scott/123456@192.168.1.100:1521/orcl) never uses your tnsnames.ora. To use your tnsnames.ora, your connection string would be:

```
sqlplus scott/123456@orcl
```

where 'orcl' is the name of the entry in tnsnames.

Third we don't know the name of the database instance.  I'd want to see the output of

```
ls -l | grep pmon
```

Fourth, Oracle 11 is old and out of support, even on supported operating systems.

If you are stuck with an Ubuntu machine (the very fact of using Ubuntu tells me this is a personal pc that you are using for self-study or schoold) your best bet would be to install Oracle VirtualBox, then use that to create a VM running a recent version of Oracle Linux, and install a recent version of Orcle on that.  I have an article on that, which is a bit dated now, at https://edstevensdba.wordpress.com/category/personal-test-systems/

Comment: Thanks for you kind answer. In which directory should I execute "ls -l | grep pmon" ？ Yes it's self-study use machine indeed , maybe I should get annother os as you suggest

Comment: It doesn't matter which directory.  Here's a career development hint.  When someone suggests you execute a command you are not familiar with, the first thing you should do is research exactly what that command does.  Google is your friend.